# How to show minDate on open with MUI DatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use react.js and have two MUI DatePicker components next to one another. One is to choose a deadline, the other to choose a date that can only be after the deadline. I've set the start component's minDate to the deadline's value so it's not possible to select a date prior to the deadline. That works, but the calendar always opens on the current month, even if minDate is several months later.

Is there a way to change the date on which the DatePicker calendar opens?

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Gucal's answer below I was able to find the solution. I guess I didn't read the documentation thoroughly enough before as I missed the defaultCalendarMonth prop. I simply put the deadlineValue as defaultCalendarMonth and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

First save the changes in DatePicker where you select the due date to a state. For the second DatePicker, give the month after the month in the state as `defaultValue={}`.

Example:

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState();
 
//Then update the datepicker default value
defaultValue={Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth() + 1, 1)}
```

Comment: Hi @Gucal, thanks so much for your comment! The solution you offered didn't work in itself as MUI DatePicker doesn't have defaultValue as a prop. That being said, it got me to look in the right section of the documentation and see the defaultCalendarMonth prop :)

Comment: Super. I've never used MaterialUI. But I wanted to express that it should have props like defaultValue. See you later...